# cannot retrieve post data from python flask

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

This is jquery ajax snippet use to send requests to localhost:5000/query
so this is my jquery snippet

```
var saveData=$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"http://localhost:5000/query",
datatype:"json",
data:{"type":"Company","name":"harshit","cin":"2014UPTC20"},
success:function(resultData){
    alert(resultData);
}
});
```

and  i cannot retrieve above sent data from python flask:-

```
@app.route('/query',methods=['POST'])   
def query_neo_dynamic():
    data="currently working"
    #return json.dumps(fetch_specific_data(type,name,i_num))
    req_data=request.get_json()
    return json.dumps(json.dumps(req_data))
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

I am getting a null 
please help

Comment: You are sending a JavaScript object, not JSON. Try saving your object in a variable like this: `var obj = {"type":"Company","name":"harshit","cin":"2014UPTC20"}` then send the data like this `data: JSON.stringify(obj),`

Comment: so how to send json???

Comment: ammended your changes but still not able to get it

Comment: got it need to add this config in $.ajax    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',